# Why does adb return zero exit status in case of "failed to connect"?

Tags: adb, exit-code

Why does `adb` return zero exit status in case of "failed to connect"?

Demo:

```
$ adb connect 123.123.123.123:123
failed to connect to '123.123.123.123:123': Connection refused
$ echo $?
0
```

Is it considered normal with `adb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.4_r1/adb/commandline.c#1092), behind the scene the `adb connect` invokes `adb_query` that returns a char array. This char array contains the result of the socket request call, something that can be displayed as string in the terminal (your 'connection refused' message for instance).

`adb_query` handles error scenarios as well but the issues that can be captured are more related to file descriptor (for socket communication) or memory allocation. When such cases happen then `echo $?` will return `1`.

That said, the answer to your question is, yes, this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: Extra question: as I understand, the `failed to connect to '123.123.123.123:123': Connection refused` comes from ADB server (or not?). Is there a similar link to the host's source code containing all "failed to", so I can grep them do determine if command executed on host failed.